# Microsoft Access 03 - ScatterPlot X-Axis not working

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I was wondering is this a bug or what, but is there a reason why the x-Axis doesn't work in Access 03's ScatterPlot. I am on Windows 7 OS and using the Microsoft Access Graphs (not excel).  Basically if I were to do a scatter plot chart, the x-axis values would all align in the arbitrary value of 1. The y-axis works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For information purposes, it turns out I was reading the graph wrong.  I thought the plot graph read the query values like this:

- X1      Y1
- X2      Y2
- X3      Y3

When it actually works like this'

- Y1     Y2      Y3
- X1     X2      X3

Update: To change it so that it reads the query the way I initially expected it to take the data, double click your chart and go to Data -> Series in Columns
http://mc-computing.com/databases/MSAccess/Charts.html

I know this is old technology, but still, some people use it. =(